# multi-stage stochastic programming interpretation

Tags: optimization, cart, probabilistic-programming

In multi-stage stochastic programming a two-stage approach is sequentially repeated. In general a two-stage model contains first-stage decisions  (e.g. production quantity) and second-stage decisions also known as recourse variables (e.g. external production supply). In between the two stages a random event takes place (e.g. customer demand).

Graphically a multi-stage optimization problem can be represented as a tree consisting of different states/nodes which are linked to probablities. So in reality at each stage only one of the nodes will "happen" (e.g. demand is 1000 OR demand is 500).

However the results of such an optimization problem provide the optimal decisions for all possible states. What is the interpretation of this result knowing in advance that not all events linked to a node are going to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a stochastic dynamic programming exercise (basically what you're describing) is a *policy*.  The policy maps states to optimal actions.  You can think of this as a contingency plan, similar to how I plan my morning commute; if, when I reach the freeway, the traffic looks really bad, I take the frontage road two entrances down and get on there; otherwise I get on the freeway.  Once I'm on the freeway, however I got there, if the morning traffic report indicates an accident on the Bay Bridge, I get off the freeway at a particular exit and go to a nice coffee shop and work from there for an hour before continuing into work, otherwise I continue on over the bridge.  On any given day, only one of these possibilities {(light traffic, no accident), (light traffic, accident), (heavy traffic, no accident), (heavy traffic, accident)} will come to pass, but I have a (pre-determined) contingency plan for dealing with whichever one actually does come to pass.  The stochastic dynamic programming algorithm (or in your case the multi-stage stochastic programming algorithm) calculates that contingency plan for me.

Comment: Your example makes it more understandable for me to comprehend the correct interpretation, for which thanks. However how would such a policy be implemented in a real life production environment. If I understood correctly it seems there are two options;

Comment: 1) Implement the optimal decision variable value of the first stage, wait for the stochastic event to happen implement the optimal recourse variable. After which you solve the model again and to the same thing. 2) Implement all stages at once in a productionplan i.e. if in the future X happens then produce this much but if the alternative to X happens then produce this much. Am I correct stating this?

Comment: Yes, you are.  Which is preferable depends on the nature of the problem.  For example, in inventory control, we might solve a 26-week horizon problem, but every week have to resolve it anyway because the 26-week horizon has stepped forward one week in time.  If your decision tree is small (few states), having the whole plan at once may be better, especially for management review, but you might still want to update it every period as, say, parameter estimates of probability distributions change.  But for other problems no update may be necessary, like some truck routing problems.